# Hash function for a smart pointer class as key for an unordered map

Tags: c++, hash, operator-overloading, smart-pointers, unordered-map

So, I have a pointer wrapper class which stores only a pointer and I need to use this class instance as a key in an unordered map. I currently have a similar setup with this pointer wrapper instances as keys to a `std::map` by overriding `bool operator<` but for an unordered map setup I would need to override two other operators `==` and `()`. I've figured how `==` operator implementation would be. but not sure about an implementation for the `()` operator. what sort of hash implementation setup should I be doing in this case? I've checked in places and most examples cover non pointer cases and they use two Key items and form hash for each and compare them for `()` implementation.

```
template <class T>
class PointerWrap{
public:
    T* pointer;
    bool operator<(const PointerWrap& other)const{return *pointer < *other.pointer;}
    bool operator==(const PointerWrap& other)const{return *pointer == *other.pointer;}
    //size_t operator()(const PointerWrap& other)const{return (*pointer)(*other.pointer);}
};
class VarType{
    bool operator<(const VarType& other)const{return this < &other;}
    bool operator==(const VarType& other)const{return this == &other;}
    size_t operator()(const VarType& other)(.?.?.}
};
//Desired setup.
std::unordered_map<PointerWrap<VarType>,Value> mymap;
```

Comment: What exactly led you to believe that the `()` overload is required?

Comment: Since you're relying on the equality operator of `T`, you unfortunately cannot use the existing `std::hash<T>` implementation (or at least you can only do so, if the equality of `T` is implemented as in `VarType`...). You probably should require a suitable specialization of `std::hash<T>` to exist and use it...

Comment: hmm, after some digging it may or may not be required if a hash method is specified someother way, in topics/resources i've checked so far, many examples/answers seem to do this by overloading `()` for a class key. however with or without doing that, i still need a hash implementation for the above pointer wrapper class instance. for which i'm still trying to figure out.

Comment: hmm you are correct @fabian, although i think im looking for a solution, that can work in most cases, like in my code example i compare the pointer addresses for VarType.  it can work mostly, and if i have a String wrapper class it can especially override `==` operator again for a tailored hash. but even if so, many of the examples im seeing for my case seem to be having another hash implementation ontop of one use within `==` but for `()` operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you seem to need a hash function only for using PointerWrappers in an unordered map, the hash function in the standard library should serve you well. (But these are not cryptographically secure hash functions so don't use them for anything else). Here is some code to show how to do this:

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
class PointerWrap {
public:
    T* pointer;
    bool operator<(const PointerWrap& other)const { return *pointer < *other.pointer; }
    bool operator==(const PointerWrap& other)const { return *pointer == *other.pointer; }
    size_t operator()(const PointerWrap& other) const {return (*pointer)(*other.pointer);}
};
class VarType {
public: // PointerWrap has no access to these operators without a public access specifier
    bool operator<(const VarType& other)const { return this < &other; }
    bool operator==(const VarType& other)const { return this == &other; }

    // Pointless to hash a object without any data
    std::size_t operator()(const VarType& other)const {
        return 0;
    }
};

// Specialization of std::hash for PointerWrap<T>
template<typename T>
class std::hash<PointerWrap<T>> {
public:
    size_t operator()(PointerWrap<T> v) const{
        return std::hash<T*>()(v.pointer);
    }
};

int main() {
    // your desired setup compiles.
    std::unordered_map<PointerWrap<VarType>, int> mymap;
    PointerWrap<VarType> a;
    mymap[a] = 5;
    std::cout << mymap[a] << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: was planning to override `()` in VarType derived classes aswell, i should've marked those operators as virtual in my examples above. but thanks your answer does clarify and so ill use std::hash for pointers and type specific cases.